# How to enable http/2 in Weblogic server

Tags: weblogic12c, http2

I want to enable http/2 for **Weblogic 12c server**. I could not find documentation for enabling http/2.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not yet. HTTP/2 is in the servlet 4.0 specification. The current release of WebLogic (12.2.1.3) implements servlet 3.1. The next major release which should support Java EE 8 (and thus servlet 4.0) should be out this year.

Comment: Thank you **Mark**.