# Weblogic 12c Enable HTTP/2

Tags: weblogic12c, http2

How is http2 protocol enabled in weblogic 12c?
I read the documentation and I can’t find anything about it.
what aplication server best implements this protocol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable http/2 in Weblogic server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010845/how-to-enable-http-2-in-weblogic-server)

Comment: Best way to get HTTP/2 is to have a web server (e.g. Apache, Nginx) in front of application server.

Comment: Thanks @BarryPollard   I found this link https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations and weblogic don’t support for http2, probably because runs over java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTTP/2** protocol is not supported in **WLS 12c**.
**WLS 14.1.x** (To be determined) will support **HTTP/2**.